# Why did my "People reached" decrease from 22k to 10k?

Tags: discussion

A few days ago, I asked [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273828/massive-change-in-people-reached-overnight) question about "People Reached"  on Meta Stack Exchange. Today I noticed that after upvoting others' answers in that question, and refreshing, my  "people reached" count changed from 22k to 10k.

Why?

Comment: @Tunaki just read question,i am asking about decrresing of that

Comment: Edited and voted to reopen. Maybe something else happened though, perhaps some other content of yours was deleted?

Comment: I find it ironic you asked a question about your Stack Overflow "People Reached" on MSE, but you asked a question about your MSE "People Reached" on MSO.

Comment: Upvoting other answers [affected your People Reached criteria](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here). As [the other answer already explained](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273830/295851), *Worth to mention, that it goes both ways... if you will get a downvote on that answer, or other answers will get enough upvotes, that 12k will be reduced again from your impact. Unlike badges, this is a "live" stat.*