# Why is there no badge or acknowledgement for impact?

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

Recently, my impact crossed **100K**, and I had been anticipating a badge or acknowledgement (don't pin me down for anticipating), but I didn't get anything.

Now, when you hover over impact, it says,

> Estimated number of times people viewed your helpful posts (based on
>   page views of your questions and questions where you wrote highly
>   ranked answers)

This indicates that the quality of posts is considered (highly ranked answers) for this statistics.

I checked *[List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)* to ensure if there is any badge for impact or not.

Why is there no badge for the 100K impact or any other figure? Does having a badge for **impact** make sense? Why or why not?

BTW, I have tagged this question as badge-request because I expressly intend for one.

I want to quote the badges' purpose defined [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256789/introducing-the-banana-split-badge-formerly-profundity-badge-controversy-badge?rq=1):

> Every single one has a defined purpose1 (although some might be less
>   obvious than others), but in general badges do one of 3 things (and
>   some do more than one):
>
> ```
> Teach users about features of the site
> Encourage positive behavior
> Reward positive contributions to the site.
> ```

**Having a badge for 100K impact highly encourages me to reach more people and therefore contribute more.**

Comment: Would this be just a single badge or a three-stage badge like bronze for 100k, silver for 1m and gold for 5m?

Comment: @Floern : A 3-stage one because you need *constant* encouragement (not always per se but..)and having 3 stage would motivate me to keep contributing.

Comment: Can we take it away if your "Impact" goes down?

Comment: @Paulie_D : It is the number of people reached. So, why would the impact go down. Its like, if someone has seen something, there is no unseeing it.

Comment: Impact goes up and down all the time. - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317909/why-did-my-people-reached-decrease-from-22k-to-10k

Comment: @Paulie_D : Fair enough. Could you refer me to any official source/evidence regarding that?

Comment: And then how do you handle upvote circle on answer that try to look like an answer on most viewed question? pos random answer form copypast other answer ona 500k view question. get an upvote from a puppet. Enjoy free impact.

Comment: @PierreLebon That same applies to many badges, not just this one.

Comment: Lets say there is a question out there that has 100K page views.  You come along and post an answer.  That answer is good so you start getting up votes.  Once you reach the minimum needed all of the sudden you have now impacted 100K people.  See the problem?  You really didn't help that many people.  Should you get a badge for that?

Comment: Hey! Good job. Congratulations. Here ya go. ◯

Comment: @Don'tPanic : Had been waiting for something like this. Problem solved!

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for the impact.

Comment: It does not seem fair that people are down voting this question in what seems to be a vote toward the opinion of the answer. I was curious about this, found this question, so it gets an up vote. If you would answer the question no, don't down vote the question, go up vote an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, as it will promote unwelcome behavior.

"Having a badge for 100K impact highly encourages me to reach more people and therefore contribute more." - would work if "impact" actually measures person's impact somehow. As of now "impact" is essentially number of views on the question where answer is posted and not tied at all to quality or value of contribution of particular user. So rewarding high impact in the current state would encourage posting answers to questions with highest number of views and potentially some vote fraud to gain necessary upvotes on such post to get answer count.

[How I reached this many people in very short period](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295440/how-i-reached-this-many-people-in-very-short-period) explains how one reaches 170K+ "impact" with answer containing *single* vote (compared to 160+ on the main answer).

<sub>answer in part is inspired by [Servy's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349097/why-is-there-no-badge-or-acknowledgement-for-impact/349124#comment472527_349102)</sub>

Answer (score 17):

It seems unnecessary.

Having a badge for "impact" would make as little sense as a badge for reputation: in both cases, *the number itself is already an acknowledgement of the achievement.*

Comment: I disagree. You do get this; https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291791/what-do-i-get-with-100k-reputationfor for 100K reputation. So, argument doesn't fail at least to get *something* for the rep/impact.

Comment: @pulp true... but that's arguably a special case. Also "impact" is a much more squishy number. It's more a marketing thing, it's not terribly meaningful in determining how people were *actually* helped by one's contributions. I don't take it very seriously.

Comment: @pulp_fiction Note that at 100k reputation you're probably up into an "impact" of several million. Also, there are fewer than 500 people who have 100k reputation. 100k impact by comparison is hardly noteworthy.

Comment: But it's fun to be powerful and famous with mountains of badges!

Comment: Wouldn't this argument also hold equally for e.g. upvotes on posts or view counts on questions? We get badges for those...

Answer (score 6):

Impact is a function of posting good questions/answers that receive lots of views.

There are already lots of badges for promoting good posts, including:

- nice question/good question/great question
- nice answer/good answer/great answer

There are badges for promoting sharing your posts and achieving high view counts, including:

- announcer/booster/publicist
- popular question/notable question/famous question

We don't need new badges for "impact" which is just an amalgam of these two things. We'd be effectively giving you badges for things you'd already received badges for.

Comment: Not really.  You can get tons of impact by just posting mediocre answers to questions where someone *else* has a really good answer (bringing in lots of views) in which you only get a few votes.  People have gotten millions of impact for answers that aren't even near earning the "nice answer" badge.  It also *does* change the incentives.  It gives more people a reason to go out searching for questions with hundreds of thousands of views and posting mediocre answers to those *already well answered* questions, in the hopes of getting a few upvotes and getting the impact.

Comment: @Servy True, I suppose encouraging people to increase their impact is actually not desirable in most cases.

Comment: @Servy : Thank you for that insight. Post it as an answer and I shall accept it.